# Subspace topology inherited by a dense set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology $T$. If $D$ is a dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R} \setminus D $ is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$, consider the collection $\mathcal{B}$ of sets $\{x\} \cup (D \cap U) $ where $x \in U$ and $U \in T$.

What subspace topology does $D$ inherit from the topology $T^*$ generated by the base $\mathcal{B}$?

I did some exploring and I think it should be the topology generated from the base defined as the collection of intersections $D \cap U$ where $U \in T$. I have some difficulties proving this, if it's even true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're suggested answer is correct, and another way to word this is that the subspace topology that $D$ inherits from $T^*$ is identical to the subspace topology on $D$ inherited from the ordinary Euclidean topology $T$ on $\mathbb R$.

To prove this one can use some set theoretical calculations. The subspace topology that $D$ inherits from $T^*$ has a basis consisting of the collection of intersections of $D$ with the elements of the collection $\mathbb B$. The strategy is to use set theoretical identities to simply the form of those intersections. Each of those intersections starts out with the following form:
\begin{align*}
(\{x\} \cup (D \cap U)) \cap D &= (\{x\} \cap D) \cup (D \cap U \cap D) \\
  &= (\{x\} \cap D) \cup (U \cap D)
\end{align*}
Now break into two cases: If $x \not\in D$ then this becomes
$$\emptyset \cup ( U \cap D ) = U \cap D
$$
whereas if $x \in D$ then this becomes
$$\{x\} \cup (U \cap D) = U \cap D
$$
where the last equation holds because $x \in U$ and $x \in D$.

But the sets of the form $U \cap D$ where $U \in T$ form a basis for the ordinary Euclidean subspace topology on $D$.